# Why is VBA copytoClipboard not working anymore?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I was using this little makro for excel until it suddenly stopped working (without me changing a thing, except maybe an office update):

```vb
Sub SumToClipboard()
  If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
  ToClipBoard (WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection))
End Sub


Public Function ToClipBoard(s)
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.SetText s
    DataObj.PutInClipboard
End Function
```

It still copys something to the clipboard but it isn't the sum of the selected cells like before, but something unidentifyable. Do you guys know if I need to change some settings or if an update rendered any of the code here useless? Am happy about any input at this point.

Comment: Not that this is your issue per se, but why are you using a function instead of a sub?

Answer (score 3):

Try being explicit about what object and data types you mean to work with. Also, a `Function` [should *return* a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52766237/1188513). Consider:

```vb
Public Sub SumSelectionToClipboard()
  If Not TypeOf Selection Is Excel.Range Then Exit Sub
  Dim total As Variant
  total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection)
  If IsNumeric(total) Then ToClipBoard CDbl(total)
End Sub


Private Sub ToClipBoard(ByVal value As Double)
    With New MSForms.DataObject
        .SetText CStr(value)
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```

Works fine here. I suspect one of the cells involved might be containing a `Variant/Error` value (e.g. `#REF!`, or `#VALUE!`, etc.). The above code doesn't send the sum to the clipboard if the result isn't a valid numeric value.

Also note that `TypeName` is a rather weak "stringly-typed" type-check, compared to `TypeOf...Is`.

Answer (score 2):

@Mathieu provided an excellent answer. But I just wanted to take this opportunity to add a function that I've used in the past.

It's almost like a property in a way instead of a function because of the ability to set and get values to the clipboard, and it could easily be made into a property, but I preferred the function because it mimics a built-in function I use in a similar programming language, WinWrapBasic (WWB) - which is almost identical to VBA without all the workbook, worksheet, document objects.

```vb
Public Function Clipboard(Optional str As Variant) As Variant

    With New MSForms.DataObject
        If IsMissing(str) Then
            .GetFromClipboard
            Clipboard = .GetText
        Else
            .SetText CStr(str)
            .PutInClipboard
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

You can set a value to the clipboard:

```vb
Clipboard "MyValue"
```

or you can retrieve the value from the clipboard:

```vb
MsgBox Clipboard
```

Comment: That's excellent! I would be hesitant to make it a property though... properties should affect instance (not global) state =)